# Can I go with my mother as a mahram for umrah?

Tags: mahram, umrah

My mother and I want to go for umrah this year and I am 17 years old and my mother is above 45. Can I accompany her as a mahram for umrah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can (at least I'm pretty sure because of your age)!
The four conditions on which scholars have consensus for a male mahram to accompany a woman while traveling are:

1. being a Muslim الإسلام
2. being mature (puberty البلوغ, mokallaf مكلف)
3. being mentally sane العاقل
4. being able to travel القدرة

(For details read [this article](http://main.islammessage.com/newspage.aspx?id=4898) in Arabic)